# Unable to perform classification and get predictions whenever inference is performed on image using tflite in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, model

Instead of getting the image prediction results, I get lost connection to the device and application crashes whenever I run inference on the image in the android application made by flutter with the help of tflite.

I have tried changing the methods such as `tflite.runModelOnImage()` to `Tflite.detectObjectOnImage()` but the result remained same.

```
  Future loadModel() async{
    String res;
    res = await Tflite.loadModel(
        model: "assets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant.tflite",
        labels: "assets/labels_mobilenet_quant_v1_224.txt",
        numThreads: 1);
    print(res);
    var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: imagePicker.path,
      numResults: 6,
      threshold: 0.05,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
    );
    setState(() {
      _recognitions = recognitions;
    });
    print(recognitions);
    await Tflite.close();
 }
```

in the main widget it is called like this:

```
RaisedButton(child: Text('check'),
onPressed: loadModel,),
```

The expected output is

```
{
  index: 0,
  label: "cat",
  confidence: 0.629
}
```

Instead I get like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8252):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:393)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8252):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8252):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8252):    ... 4 more
I/Process ( 8252): Sending signal. PID: 8252 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```